# Jquery Validation remote method always shows invalid

Tags: javascript, python, django, formvalidation.io

I am trying to validate an html function with django and the JavaScript [FormValidation plugin](https://formvalidation.io). I want validation
to check if the inserted email already exists,

This is my validation remote

```
           email: {
            validators: {
              notEmpty: {
                message: 'email field can not be empty'
              },
              emailAddress: {
                message: 'is not a valid email'
              },
              remote: {
                message: 'email is already in use',
                url: '/validate_email/',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                  email: function() {
                    return $('#email').val();
                  }
                },
              },
            },
          },
```

The url calls to my view def which is

```
def validate_email(request):
    email = request.GET.get('email', None)
    data = not Vendors.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists()
    if data is True:
        data = "true"
    else:
        data = "false"

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

I am getting a correct "true" or "false" JsonResponse, but the message always shows that the email is already in use and keep asking me to correct it.

I tried passing the JsonResponse as true or false without "", also tried passing the JsonResponse as `is_taken: true` or `is_taken: false`.

Comment: You are not using the jQuery Validate plugin as originally tagged and described.  Your code syntax clearly indicates that you're using the JavaScript "FormValidation" plugin here:  https://formvalidation.io.  Please pay better attention when writing and tagging your question.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Django view, you need to return a JSON response in the following format:

```
return JsonResponse({"valid": data})
```

The FormValidation plugin will understand that the email is valid if the response is `"valid":true` and invalid if the response is `"valid": false`.

Comment: Except jQuery Validate is not the plugin that he's using.  See:   https://formvalidation.io/guide/validators/remote/